# Derived Column expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl

How to get the difference in hours between two datetime ?

```sql
CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar (5),a.[Entry_Date],108) <=(a.[Answer_Date]) THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar,a.[Answer_Date]-a.[Entry_Date],8),5)  
ELSE ' ' END AS ExecutionTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use [DATEDIFF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/datediff-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017) function within a derived column:

*Syntax*

> DATEDIFF(datepart, startdate, endate)

*Example*

```
DATEDIFF("Hour", [Entry_Date], [Answer_Date])
```

Comment: Thank you. This what I get :1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: Thank you Yahfoufi !I think I have to do some cast operation.

Comment: @EmanuelShirbint the DATEDIFF function returns an integer, make sure you are not linking the result column into a datetime column in destination

Comment: 2018-11-26 11:55:26.500

Comment: Answer_Date
2018-11-26 11:55:26.500

Comment: Entry_Date
2018-11-26 09:17:44.567

Comment: Data Type in Derived Column is : four-byte signed integer [DT_I4]

Comment: [Add a Data viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/add-a-data-viewer-to-a-data-flow?view=sql-server-2014) to check the data resulted from the derived column

Comment: @EmanuelShirbint if data type is DT_I4 = integer, then how you mentioned that it returns `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` in the first comment

Comment: Answer_Date and Entry_date in (DT_DBTIMESTAMP) format

Comment: @EmanuelShirbint what is the result of the derived column? what is the data type of the destination column?

Comment: @EmanuelShirbint feel free to [mark this answer as accepted](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

use DATEDIFF() Function, like

select DATEDIFF(hour,'2019-07-23 10:10:10',getdate())